# Struct's pointer and how to access elements

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

i wanted to create a little example for struct's witch constructor and destructor, but my problem is that i can't "print" Zahlen[0] and i don't know why?

Thank for any kind of help.

Maybe i have to print it with pointer argument?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct IntList{
    int *memory;
    int size;

    // Konstruktur
    IntList(unsigned initialSize = 0) {
        memory = new int[initialSize];// Speicher reservieren (0 erlaubt)
        size = initialSize;
    }

    //Destruktor
    ~IntList() {
        delete []memory; // Speicher freigeben
    }

    // Access Elemnts
    int &operator[](unsigned index) {
        if (index>=size) {throw std::out_of_range("out of bounds");}
        return memory[index];
    }
};



int main()
{
    IntList *Numbers = new IntList(10);
    Numbers[0] = 1;
    cout << Numbers[0] << endl;
    delete Numbers;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't provide an overload of `operator<<`, so it's not clear by what magic you expect `cout << Numbers[0]` to work. What output, exactly, do you expect this line to produce, and why?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OP wants to use `operator[]` which returns `int &` there is no magic.

Comment: C++ is not java you do not have to create everything on heap, in this case creating `Numbers` by `new` gives you nothing but troubles.

Comment: i know, just wanted to understand how you handle something on the heap :)

Comment: In this case problem is not that object on the heap, but that you deal with type `Numbers *` not `Numbers` or `Numbers &`  etc and that's different types. And again unlike Java in C++ not everything is a pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IntList *Numbers = new IntList(10);
Numbers[0] = 1;
cout << Numbers[0] << endl;
```

`Numbers` are of type pointer-to-IntList. Pointers have had array-like semantics in C family since time immemorial, so `Numbers[0]` is not a call to `IntList::operator[]` but rather merely a pointer's first element, that `IntList` you've allocated on heap.

Either create it on stack:

```
IntList Numbers(10);
Numbers[0] = 1;
cout << Numbers[0] << endl;
// automatically destroyed on exiting scope
```

Or at least address it correctly:

```
IntList *Numbers = new IntList(10);
(*Numbers)[0] = 1;
cout << (*Numbers)[0] << endl;
delete Numbers;
```

Comment: if im using the first solution,the constructor of my struct initializes the array on the heap. And at the end of the main function, will my destructor be called or is it some kind of automatic destructor?

Comment: @vanderub your destructor will be called

Comment: @vanderub A type can have only one destructor, so when you define one it becomes the one that is called each time an object of your type is destroyed. It is called at the end of block on a temporary object created inside that block. It is called on an object in free storage when deleted. It is even called on a local object when an exception was thrown and not caught somewhere inside local scope. As a completely unrelated, STL has many useful RAII-types, like `std::vector`, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::array` that can do all the job with pointers and sizes for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you made `Numbers` a pointer to a `IntList`.  `IntList *Numbers = new IntList(10);` needs to be `IntList Numbers = IntList(10);` so that you have a `IntList` object and not a pointer to one.  This will allow you to call `IntList::operator[]` instead of the `operator[]` of the pointer which just gives you an `Intlist`

Then you need to get rid of `delete Numbers;` as well since `Numbers` is no longer a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to write

```
IntList Numbers(10);
Numbers[0] = 1;
cout << Numbers[0] << endl;
```

The issue with your snippet

```
IntList *Numbers;
auto thisIsNotWhatYouThinkItIs = Numbers[0];
```

is that the second statement returns `IntList` because `Numbers` is a pointer to the `IntList` instance.

Comment: I'm getting now Error for delete " type 'struct IntList' argument given to 'delete', expected pointer delete Numbers;

Comment: The line with `delete Numbers` must be deleted.